# How to display two cells each with different functionality in the same tableView simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableView.

I have tableViewCellOne. tableViewCellOne allows text input and image input by the user which gets saved in a database. This part works fine.

I want to build tableViewCellTwo. This cellTwo has a different function than cellOne. cellTwo will retrieve this data and display it.

I want both cells to be visible at the same time. tableViewCellOne above, and tableViewCellTwo below, on the same tableView. Here is the relevant portion of the code I wrote. The way that it works as of now, it only displays tableViewCellOne which is not my intent. This code is written in my TableViewController.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.

     if (indexPath.row == 0) {

      let cellIdentifier = "MyTableViewCell"
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        // Fetches the appropriate data for the data source layout.
        let data = myData[indexPath.row]
        cell.MyData1.text = data.1
        cell.MyData2.image = data.2
        cell.MyData3.text = data.3
        return cell

     } else {

      let cellIdentifier = "TheirDataTableViewCell"
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TheirDataTableViewCell

        // Fetches the appropriate data for the data source layout.
        let data = theirData[indexPath.row]
        cell.TheirData1.text = data.1
        cell.TheirData2.image = data.2
        cell.TheirData3.text = data.3
        return cell
    }
}
```

With this if else statement, I am trying to say: when we are loading cell 1 then load the following data, when we are loading cell2 then load the following other data. But I think instead its interpreting it as: if (something) load cell1, if (something else) load cell2. I could be way off base with that diagnosis though.

How do I display two cells each with different functionality in the same tableView simultaneously?

Comment: What do you return in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`?

Comment: Thats a very good question. I wrote [ return myData ] which is a data model. But I did not return the theirData data model. It says that after I return the first one, any code after that will not be read so I dont know how to return both

Comment: You have to return an `Int`. The compiler should warn you when you return something else.

Comment: Actually, in your case, in numberOfRowsInSection you should return 2. As for the rest, there are no issues in displaying mixed types of cells in a tableview, and looks you are doing it right.